# Does ASP.NET Identity work with an on-premise Active Directory without ADFS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I can find examples using the ActiveDirectoryMembership-Provider, but I can't find information on how to authenticate with an Active Directory in an intranet context with ASP.NET Identity.

The Identity framework is supposed to replace Membership- and Role-providers, but it doesn't seem to allow authentication to on-premise Active Directories without ADFS.

Is there a way to use Identity with a non-ADFS Active Directory?
If there is not, is it recommended to use the ActiveDirectoryMembership-Provider instead?

I am currently using an LdapConnection (System.DirectoryServices.Protocols) to bind a user to the AD and storing the username a session variable. Then I can check if the users is logged in the PreInit event of each page. But I am looking for a way to use application wide authentication with a way to check for user roles in the AD.

Comment: Do you use self-hosted OWIN?

Comment: No, I am using ASP.NET Web Forms on IIS. Didn't manage to get OWIN to work at all. Most examples use MVC and don't work with Web Forms.

Comment: If this is your case, I can suggest you to use [windows authentication feature of IIS itself](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication).

Comment: @stukselbax Thanks for your suggestion, but windows authentication does not seem to allow SignOut or switching of users/accounts (without restarting the browser) as well as anonymous access to a subset of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the ADVAPI32.dll, to validate the user from Intranet Active Directory.

```
[DllImport("ADVAPI32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

LogonUser(userName, domainName, password, 3, 1, ref token);
```

This code could help you validate user with Active Directory.

Comment: I can already validate the user and updated my question accordingly. Sorry if the initial question wasn't clear enough.